# With Server-Sent Events (SSE) does PHP not reach the max_execution_time?

Tags: php, server-sent-events

All the examples of SSE that I have looked at use an infinite while loop plus sleep cmd on the server side to fetch data and return it to the client side - does the PHP max_execution_time not come into effect here? Or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

max_execution_time will stop that php script, but SSE reconnects automatically

Comment: Does that mean for every client there will be a php script running on the server? I thought the thing about SSE is that 1 server script runs and it pushes data to connected clients.

Comment: PHP is a language, not software; but most of current web servers launches php process for each client; it's better to use "event-driver" server